# React-Redux: mapDispatchToProps methods not found

Tags: reactjs, redux

It's my impression that methods added to mapDispatchToProps should then be accessible by this.props. When I call these methods "Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onHighlight is not a function" is raised. 
Anyone know what's going on? Been trying a bunch of different alternatives for mapDispatchToProps but none of them work.

```
   import React from 'react';
    import { addHighlight, deleteHighlight, selectHighlight } from 'actions/highlight';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import jquery from 'jquery';
    import { styles } from './styles.scss';

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
        onHighlight: (start, end, selectedText) => {
          dispatch(addHighlight(start, end, selectedText));
        },
        onDeleteHighlight: (source) => {
          dispatch(deleteHighlight(source));
        },
        onSelectHighlight: (source) => {
          dispatch(selectHighlight(source));
        }
      };
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return { highlights: state.highlights,
               currentTopic: state.currentTopic,
               selectedHighlight: state.selectedHighlight,};
    }

    ...
    Other code about Highlight object 
    ...

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(Highlight);
```

Comment: two things to check: 1 - Make sure you are using the connected version of your component instead of accidentally using the unconnected version. 2- make sure `this` is actually your component instance.  Make sure you are not calling an event handler with `this` unbound.  Its hard to say more unless you post some of your component and how you are trying to call `onHighlight`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [bindActionCreators](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html):

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return bindActionCreators({
        onHighlight: addHighlight,
        onDeleteHighlight: deleteHighlight,
        onSelectHighlight: selectHighlight
      }, dispatch);
    }
```